# Cypher read CSV, add label to dataset and create index

Tags: neo4j, cypher

In Cypher, I want to read two CSV files, add labels to them, define indexes on some fields, and finally relate the two datasets by a common field between the two.

How can i do that? Something like this:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///1.csv' AS row
CREATE (:A {PROGRAM_CODE:row.PRODUCT_CODE,PRODUCT_NAME:row.PROGRAM_NAME,Stuid:row.CUSTOMER_NO})
CREATE INDEX ON :A(PROGRAM_CODE)
CREATE INDEX ON :A(CUSTOMER_NO)
RETURN count(A);
```

The same for reading the second CSV as labelled B, and then make relation On A.CUSTOMER_NO and B.CUSTOMER_NO and finally visualize the graph showing the PRODUCT_NAMES and Customers as relations.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried the code you wrote? Does it work, or what is the error? People here usually do not write code for you, but we are good at solving problems with it. :)

Comment: No the code doesnt work, i just tried to explain what I need: 1: read a csv content and assign a label to it("A"), then 2- Index two fields ("PROGRAM_CODE" "Customr_No"). At the moment I can do the above items but they should be done separately.  like creating constraint at first, then reading the file and then assigning index into them. i wanted to do it all in one code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to do something like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_NO_CONSTRAINT IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:A) REQUIRE n.CUSTOMER_NO IS NODE KEY

USING PERIODIC COMMIT
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM 'file:///1.csv' as row
CREATE (:A {PROGRAM_CODE:row.PRODUCT_CODE, PRODUCT_NAME:row.PROGRAM_NAME, Stuid:row.CUSTOMER_NO})
```

Creating the constraint that CUSTOMER_NO is a node key means the property must exist and be unique for each node. The constraint exists in the database even if there are no A nodes.

If you just want an index and not a key:

```
CREATE BTREE INDEX CUSTOMER_NO_INDEX
FOR (n:A)
on (n.CUSTOMER_NO)
```

And do the same with PROGRAM_CODE.

Extra tip: While Cypher lets you label nodes, relationships, and properties however you wish, the naming conventions are:
labels: LabelName (caps starting at first word)
properties: customerNo (caps starting at second word)
relationships: MY_RELATIONSHIP (all caps, underscores)

That makes it easier to understand the structure from just looking at the code. :)

Hope that helps!